# Show Two Languages at once

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization

Fisrt of all i am following [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) guide for localization which is the official guideline of flutter but at

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld
```

It gives error as null

I think this is maybe because I recently updated flutter to `2.10` please confirm if that is the case

I want to achieve this kind of results like English on right and Urdu Language of Left which i don't know how to do that because in samples and guides they just show how to change overall app language not just for some strings

[image]

Also for time being, I have used `easy_localization: 3.0.0` but still the problem is how i support multiple language at once with this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use localization for this part - drawer widget - text items
2. wrap drawer widget with Directionality widget to prevent it from mirroring and make text in the same place.
3. pop the drawer after using switch widget.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as ltr;


drawer: Directionality(
    textDirection: ltr.TextDirection.ltr,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('English'),
              Text('عربي'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('English'),
              Text('عربي'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```